# How to enable mobile network in Android Tablet

Tags: karbonn-smart-tab-7

I have got [Karbonn Ta-Fone A34](http://www.karbonntablet.com/ta-fone-a34-with-dual-sim-and-calling/) tablet. By default its mobile network options is permanently inactive. 
Now I have rooted my tablet and want to enable to mobile network option. 
Is there any way I can browse the Android System files and make changes there to enable the mobile network or if there is any app to do this.

Comment: yes there are lots of widgets, which allow directly from home screen..  you can use go widgets..  or simply search network enable widget etc.

Comment: Disable means it is permanently inactive

Comment: @Sidh If you want better answers, you should update the question to mention that you're using an external 3G modem, and answer my question about SIM cards.

Answer (score 5):

According to the specs you linked, this tablet doesn't support 3G mobile networks, only GSM. To enable the mobile network features, you need to buy a 3G USB dongle and connect it to the tablet.

Comment: Even after connecting the dongle, Mobile network option remain inactive..

Comment: Is there a 3G SIM card in the dongle?

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you can't; the network specs are;  2G: GSM 900, GSM 1800, that does not mean it has something to do with the software used or OS, its network adapter can only support 2G network.

That said, it doesn't mean you shouldn't try some apps.here are some you can give a shot at; [2G/3G](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.talkingnmouse&hl=en), [network conversion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Network_2G_3G_Conversion_209074), [network change](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Network_2G_3G_Change_209074&hl=ent)...some may work and others may not. You could also get a 3G modem to work this out for you. Some applications will show you that the network is changed to 3G, I wouldn't buy that though. Get some ways of testing your network speed after installing an app just to make sure. Let me know when it works.glad to help.

Comment: Just want to let you know that all of these links are dead; the apps are not available anymore.